# Python Values replacement in list

Tags: python, list

I have to be making stupid mistake, but I really have no idea why it's working this way. Can anyone expain it to me please?

```
placement = [0]*4
for image in placement:
    image = 1
print(placement)
```

output:`[0, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: `for image in placement` assigns each element in `placement` to the variable `image`. Reassigning `image` does not affect the original list.

Comment: This will replace numbers in placement, and you could argue, that I'm creating new variable "e": `placement = [1 for e in placement]`

Comment: No, it won't. `placement = [1 for e in placement]` replaces the rebinds the name `placement` to a *new list*, one made from taking each element in the original list, binding each one in order to the name `e`, and generating a new value from it, specifically here, a value that completely ignores `e` (the literal value `1`). The generated values are collected in a new list, which gets bound to the name `placement`, but it doesn't change *the contents of the original list*, and you can verify this: `placement = [0] * 4; original = placement; placement = [1 for e in placement]; print(original)`

Comment: You have mistaken ideas about how assignment works in Python. Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say:

```
image = 1
```

You're only changing the value of the variable called `image`; in other words, you're binding the *name* `image` to a new value. This doesn't affect the original list at all.

In more detail: when you say `for image in placement`, what happens is that on each iteration of the `for`-loop, the name `image` is bound to the value in the appropriate position in the list. Assigning to it again only re-binds it to some other value.

The `for`-loop above is equivalent to:

```
  image = placement[0]
  image = 1  # does not change placement[0]
  image = placement[1]
  image = 1  # does not change placement[1]
  image = placement[2]
  image = 1  # does not change placement[2]
  image = placement[3]
  image = 1  # does not change placement[3]
```

To change items in the list, you can assign to a specific index:

```
for i in range(len(placement)):
  placement[i] = 1  # assigns into a specific position in the list, changing its contents
```

Answer (score 2):

When iterating with `for in` over an array, if modifying the resulted element from each iteration will not affect the original array.
Use `enumerate` to iter over the array with the index and assign with the index

```
for index, image in enumerate(placement):
    placement[index] = image + 1
```

Comment: Or in this case use the dedicated operator `placement[index] += 1`, but please note that OP never mentioned incrementation of the original value, just new assignment.

Comment: I know and I have written an assignment with an incremented value for him to know what difference operations he can make